# I want to put a title to my jquery popup

Tags: jquery, html, css

I was trying to put a header  title for jquery popup but it is not showing.

how to change jquery dialog title here is the code we are using this will show it will show blank  when i  put  like this

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addNewsport" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" >

  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document" style="">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="modal-header" title="Dialog Title!">
       <img src="../img/sport.jpg" style="widows:70px;height:70px">
       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Register New sport</h4>
      </div>
       <div id="sportModelBox"></div>      
      <div class="modal-body">
        <table class="table table-condensed" style="background-color:#CCC">
        <caption><h3><small>sport Details</small><h3></caption>
        <!------- Select sport   --------------------->
        <tr><td>sport Name</td><td ><input type="text" name="sportName"   id="sportName"/>      </td></tr>
        <tr><td>sport NO</td><td ><input type="text" name="sportNo"   id="sportNo"/>      </td></tr>


             </table>
             <hr/>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"  onClick="window.location.reload();">CLOSE</button>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="SAVE" onClick="saveNewsport();"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

any idea would be great

Comment: refer : http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp

Comment: Most browser's will show a tooltip when a title attribute is used and you hover over the element.  Is this what you are expecting?  Do you have a working example?